# I need confirmation regarding timezone displaying EST

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimezone

I am wondering if the code below will correctly display Eastern time correctly no matter what (day light savings or when it isn't day light savings). Right now my App isn't displaying data correctly because of day light savings. This code seems to work well now, but I don't want to find out in a few months that this time doesn't adjust correctly.

```
 [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"US/Eastern"]
```

Comment: `Right now my App isn't displaying data correctly because of day light savings.`  `This code seems to work well now.`  Aren't there 2 sentences contradicting each other?

Comment: Sorry, my App was using another timezone logic  '[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"EST"];'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,

For March 10 2015, it displays

```
US/Eastern (EDT) offset -14400 (Daylight)
```

For March 1 2015, it displays

```
US/Eastern (EST) offset -18000
```